# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returning nil or current date

Tags: ios

I'm having some issues trying to format a string into NSDate.
This is my code.

```
        NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormat setTimeZone:outputTimeZone];
        [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]] ;

        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

this is the string that I'm trying to format.

**"09/11/2016 12:27:05"**

this is the result I get

**2016-11-09 04:48:29 UTC**

Please help I have been trying various solutions and formats but to no avail.

---

> After the call to dateFromString, add the line NSLog("str = %@, date = %@", dateString, myDate);. Update your question with the output of that log statement. – rmaddy 59 mins ago

This is my output

**str = 09/11/2016 14:13:35, date = 2016-11-09 06:13:35 +0000**

Comment: date hase un ordered format, check ur timezone

Comment: After the call to `dateFromString`, add the line `NSLog("str = %@, date = %@", dateString, myDate);`. Update your question with the output of that log statement.

Comment: what you want as output ?

Comment: If you are printing NSDate in console log then you will get it in UTC, try to convert date with your date formatter to string and see the result

Answer (score -1):

Use timeZonewithAbbrevation instead of default timeZone.

Replace `NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];` with

// For GMT

NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"];

OR

// For UTC

```
NSTimeZone *outputTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me! 
I used 
timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"
and my output was 
str = 09/11/2016 14:32:29, date = 2016-11-09 14:32:29 +0000
the format is still different though but what matters is the time is correct! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, it's not correct. You misunderstand.